# How do I unify two or more Signals in elerea?

Tags: haskell, frp, elerea

Is there something like `reactive-bananas` `union` function in `elerea`?

```
union :: Signal a -> Signal a -> Signal a
```

This just merges the two signals into one stream. Ideally I am searching for an efficient union of a large number (14k) of signals:

```
unions :: [Signal a] -> Signal a
```

There doesn't seem to be anything in the docs, nor is there anything that I could recognize as a building block therefor.

---

Edit: except for maybe this:

```
unionSignal :: a -> Signal a -> Signal a -> SignalGen p (Signal a)
unionSignal initial a b = do
  (s,f) <- execute $ external initial
  _ <- effectful1 f a
  _ <- effectful1 f b
  return s
```

But ... that is just ugly and doesn't capture the idea of `union`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's nothing quite like `union` for elerea's signal because of how an elerea network is modeled.  An `elerea` signal contains exactly one value at each step, so there's no sensible way to combine arbitrary values at the same time.  However, there are a few different ways you could combine signals, depending on how the values should be combined.

```
unions :: [Signal a] -> Signal [a]
unions = sequence    -- or Data.Traversable.sequenceA
```

or you can fold directly over the inputs

```
foldS :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [Signal a] -> Signal b
foldS f b signals = foldr (\signal acc -> f <$> signal <*> acc) (return b) signals
-- I think a right fold is more efficient, but it depends on elerea's internals and I'm not sure
```

If you don't actually care about the value and just want to make sure the signal gets switched in, you can use

```
unions_ :: [Signal a] -> Signal ()
unions_ = sequence_
```